# how to scroll embedded chromium in Delphi

Tags: delphi, scroll, chromium-embedded

Hi is there any way to simulate the [Delphi embedded chromium](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) scroll position? or simulate SPACE key to scroll when pressing a TButton.

Comment: Have you tried using `Chromium1.Browser.Host.SendKeyEvent` to send it a Space-key press?

Comment: @MartynA, thanx for your suggestion. I am trying find sample in the web but i haven't found any. I will make experiment with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is inject some javascript that will scroll to the bottom

```
ChromiumComponent.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
  'window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);'
);
```

Works great for one way communication to the page you are on.